# Link to meta queues broken on wide screens

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design

The last update broke the link to meta queues.

On wide screens it looks like this:

[image]

Previously this link was on the bottom of the page and at mobile devices it still looks as yesterday:

[image: r]

Comment: Can't repro on meta.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Repro'd on 3440x1440 Chrome / Mac

Comment: @TimPost there are also some localization issues. Perhaps the strings "Recent reviews", "Meta reviews", and "Choose a task to get started" are not used in localization engine. If you wish I could submit a related bug report.

Comment: Oops, I'll get this fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’ve committed a fix for this. The meta link had the wrong parent element, so I just moved that block into a spot that makes sense. This will go live in the next build.

Comment: Can you confirm the [localization issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322008/link-to-meta-queues-broken-on-wide-screens#comment1053727_322008) here?

Comment: We changed some copy there, yep. Those strings will get translated at some point.